# Codeigniter HMVC RuntimeException when load model in another modules

Tags: codeigniter, runtimeexception, hmvc

I have a new problem with Codeigniter HMVC when deploy my project to hosting Unix (it works well on localhost)

```
$this->load->model('User_management/Muser_management');
```

When I call User_management model file in User_profile controllers it throws an error:

**Type: RuntimeException
Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Muser_management**

The same problem with other controllers when when load model from another modules

My structure

```
>root
  >application
     >modules

       >User_management
          >controllers
             User_management.php
          >models
             Muser_management.php

       >User_profile
          >controllers
             User_profile.php
          >models
             Muser_profile.php
```

My Muser_mangement file:

```
<?php 
    defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Muser_management extends MY_Model{

        public function get_listuser()
        {   
            $this->db->select('id,label,email,role');
            $user=$this->db->get('user');
            return $user->result();
        }
}
?>
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: Just for testing purpose, check with extending `CI_Model` (instead of `MY_Model`) if working. And don't close `?>` tag at the end of files.

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVE]Anyway, I have fixed it. The solution is:

_the folder name of modules must be in lowercase
_the controller and model files name must be in uppercase for the 1st letter only
_the class in controller and model must be in uppercase for the 1st letter only